# Didnt receive any mail from My Website...?

Tags: php, html

I am working on simple website but facing some problems with contact form, I try all type of settings but Its didnt work.

The problem is When I fill form and press submit button then It will be shows "Message sent successfully" But I cant receive any mail to my mail ID.

So What Can I do...???

My `PHP CODE`: file name is "`mail.php`"

```
<?php
  echo '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">';
  echo '<head>';
  echo '<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />';
  echo '<title>';
  echo $title;
  echo '</title>';
  echo '</head>';
  echo '<body>';  

$to = "anup.karanjkar08@gmail.com;
$subject = $_REQUEST['Name'] + "Sent a Mail";
$message = $_REQUEST['Message'] ;
$from = $_REQUEST['Email'] ;
$headers = "From:" . $from;
$a= mail($to,$subject,$message);
if ($a) {
  echo "Message sent successfully";
}
else
{
  echo "Sorry there is an error.";
}
echo '</body>';
echo '</html>';

?>
```

My `HTML CODE`

```
<form name="contact_to_infrasure" id="infrasure"  action="mail.php" method="POST">
          <div class="row-fluid">
            NAME<br><input  type="text" name="Name">
          </div>
          <div class="row-fluid">
            EMAIL<br><input  type="text" name="Email"><br>
          </div>
          <div class="row-fluid">
            MESSAGE<br><textarea rows="5" style="width: 60%"  name="Message"></textarea><br>
          </div>
          <div class="row-fluid">
           <!--  <input class="span3" type="submit" value="SEND MESSAGE"> -->
          <button class="btn" type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="">SEND MESSAGE</button> 
          </div>
      </form>
```

Please Help Me...!!!

Comment: Did you tried to execute the code.?I am sure that this will give you only syntax errors

Comment: Contact to your hosting provider. My hosting provider doesn't allow mail() function.

Comment: I guess `$to = "anup.karanjkar08@gmail.com;` should be `$to = "anup.karanjkar08@gmail.com";`

Comment: enable E_NOTICE & check are you getting any notice.

Comment: Your best bet is to check whether your hosting provider has mail() enabled. Also, the domain/server itself could be black listed on gmail. Are you able to read bounced emails sent to the server?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Not receiving email from the PHP mail() method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19070872/not-receiving-email-from-the-php-mail-method)

Comment: How to set Mail()enable option Can u tell me...???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed these lines, concatination used in php is `.` not `+`,  `+` used in javscript
            `$subject = $_REQUEST['Name'] . "Sent a Mail";`

```
        <?php
          echo '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">';
          echo '<head>';
          echo '<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />';
          echo '<title>';
          echo $title;
          echo '</title>';
          echo '</head>';
          echo '<body>';  

            $to = "anup.karanjkar08@gmail.com";
            $subject = $_REQUEST['Name'] . "Sent a Mail"; // changed this line  removed + 
            $message = $_REQUEST['Message'] ;
            $from = $_REQUEST['Email'] ;
            $headers = "From:" . $from;
            $a= mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers); // added headers here
            if ($a) {
              echo "Message sent successfully";
            }
            else
            {
              echo "Sorry there is an error.";
            }
            echo '</body>';
            echo '</html>';

        ?>
```

Reason for mail not sending,

**ISP Blocks**

An increasing number of ISP’s are blocking port 25, the port used to send email. Many of the major ISP’s, including NetZero, MSN, Earthlink, AT&T, Comcast and Verizon, block port 25 in an attempt to control spam. If your ISP blocks port 25, then you will be unable to send email out of your server. This is not a server problem but a direct block by your ISP. We can often work around these blocks by configuring your mail server to listen to additional ports.

Ref: http://www.rackaid.com/resources/cannot-send-email-how-to-fix-email-sending-and-receiving-errors/

Answer (score 4):

First add ending " in this line.

```
$to = "anup.karanjkar08@gmail.com";
```

Then try to run if it works.

Check with hosting provider that mail function in php is working.

Comment: I edited that thinking it was a typo - I guess he never ran his code.

Comment: He said that it shows message, so probably that was just typo and answer is not correct.

Comment: @FaddishWorm You just gave the answer in an edit of the question. xd

Comment: lol yea I know - my bad. I noticed coz of the syntax highlighting.

Comment: He said the script prints "Message sent successfully". So that was a typo when copying to SO. This is not the right answer.

Comment: Hi its just copy paste mistake friend it's already there $to = "anup.karanjkar08@gmail.com";